# How to activate full screen control DOTS (SDK14)

Tags: android, user-interface, fullscreen

Does anybody know what i mean?

In fullscreen mode of the new camera app on my galaxy nexus the control buttons are changing into 3 dots.

How can i activate that programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

within your activity.

*See [`View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE)*

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard Options Menu.  On 3.0+ it creates those dots, in 2.3.3- you access it with the menu key.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html