# Learning how to set a flag on a view in Android

Tags: java, android, flags

I'm trying to use this flag `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE` on a view. My problem goes deeper than that though. My real problem is that I'm really bad at navigating the documentation to find out how to actually implement this. I find myself in this predicament a lot. Can anyone tell me how to learn how to set a flag, but by using the documentation and not looking for someone to post some sample code for me to "steal"? Let's say all I had was eclipse and all of the downloaded android documentation, and I didn't know how to set this, how could I learn? This is more of a "learning to program" type of question, but a genuine question nonetheless and I hope someone can help me out.

The best I can comeup with from reading the documentation:

```
setContentView(R.layout.start);
setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE):
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to work offline quite often (while travelling) and am quite experienced problem-solving with just the reference documentation; so it is possible! I'll start with a quick overview of the Android SDK Reference, and ease into some information about flags while preserving your chance (and hopefully tools) to solve your particular problem yourself.

Most API reference documents, especially those generated using Javadoc-type tools, follow similar conventions; so once you're comfortable with Android's reference documentation, you should be able to translate other documentation as well.

I recommend you *bookmark the package* index page (if you haven't already) of your reference documentation:

- http: // developer.android.com/reference/packages.html *-or-*
- {your local "android-sdk" folder}/docs/reference/packages.html.

On Windows, the full default path should be similar to:

- file:///C:/Program%20Files/Android/android-sdk/docs/reference/packages.html *-or-*
- file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Android/android-sdk/docs/reference/packages.html

> - **Header Search Box**: The search box in the upper right is great for searching the documentation.
> - When *online*, a search for "flags" will result in all references throughout the documentation.
> - When *offline*, the search box will only provide hints/links for form of package and class names; typing "intent" will offer "android.content.Intent", but you will find "flags" decidedly unhelpful.

## Packages Index Page

On the left you'll find the Android Packages List with links to each package, while the body of the page lists the packages with a short introduction and link to each.

## Package Pages

Clicking on a package (such as "android.content") will bring up a page summarizing the package and its contents, as well as populating the Package Contents List (beneath the Android Packages List) with the package's constituent interfaces, exceptions, and classes such as "Intent".

## Class Pages

*Example: Intent class*

- http: // developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
- android-sdk/docs/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Clicking on a interface, exception, or class (such as "Intent") will bring up an extremely long page of information about it. At the top of each class page you'll find the Class Definition (aka Signature) followed by the Class Overview section which explains the object's purpose and implementation. There is also a list of jump links to the other sections of the page:

> Nested Classes | Constants | Inherited Constants | Fields | Ctors | Methods | Inherited Methods

## Finding Useful References

If you don't know what you're looking for, I suppose you can start reading pretty much anywhere; but given a specific need, such as implementing flags, a basic knowledge of OOP will get you started.
Since you want to learn how to add flags (actions are Methods) to a View (an Object,) looking at the Methods for a View is an excellent place to start your search, as is View's Class Overview section.

I'll leave View for you to read later since you said you wanted to learn how to learn :)

> **Browser Search**: Don't forget to make use of your browser's built-in search feature, often [CTRL]+[F] on windows. Searching for a term such as "flag" will allow us to quickly browse through all occurrences of it (217 of flag!) on the page, but you can quickly try a few related terms and phrases (the more precise the better) to get a more refined/reduced match set, then iterate through some. By quickly trying a few more terms, I was able to find what I wanted: "flags"(67), "add flag"(0), and "addflag"(6 matches - winner!)

## Navigating a Class Page

Continuing to use the android.content.Intent class page as an example, clicking the jump link for Methods will quickly reveal **addFlags()**, and a bit of scrolling will reveal **setFlags()**. Both methods take a single *int* as their argument; however, the text refers to this single *int* using the plural name "flags" for good reason: you can squeeze quite a few flags into a single int, because each flag is stored as a specific bit! (I'll explain this a bit more below.)

At the bottom of each method is a "see also" subsection that often contains usefully related links. Both the flag methods we found, addFlags() and setFlags(), reference each other in their "see also" section, and setFlags() also contains links to all of the relevant flag constants. These flag constants, each have a name beginning with "FLAG_" by convention. Here are the "Constants" entries for a couple commonly used intent flags:

> - int    FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK    If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.
> - int    FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP    If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Clicking on the constants' names will jump us further down the page, to where each of these constants is explained in greater detail including listing their actual values in both base-10 (decimal) and base-16 (hex).

*Remember that Java uses a C-style prefix of '0x' to differentiate hexadecimal numbers, and that this prefix does not affect the value aside from identifying it's numeric base.*

> - FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK shows a constant value of 268435456 (0x10000000).
> - FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP has a constant value of 536870912 (0x20000000).

These numbers may seem random and arbitrary, but they aren't - each is actually a single switched-on bit in an otherwise zero byte, making our flags in base-2 (binary) seem more logical:

> - 00010000000000000000000000000000 and
> - 00100000000000000000000000000000.

## How to Add and Set Flags in a bit-mask

To apply both to an intent, you can use either setFlags (discard pre-existing flags) or addFlags (keep all flags) like so:

> - someExampleIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
> - *Take special notice of the vertical bar, "|", between our flags; in Java it is the "bitwise-or" operator.*

Basically, the bitwise-or does a bit-by-bit comparison of the input int's that returns true(1) if any comparison bit is true, otherwise returning false(0). bitwise-or, Yea!

So bitwise-or comparison of our bit-masks will yield:

> - 00010000000000000000000000000000 |
> - 00100000000000000000000000000000 =
> - 00110000000000000000000000000000

Be careful to **never use addition (+) with bit-masks**! It's perfect for creating intermittent bugs; it will yield the same result as bitwise-or when merging two numbers.. (hold for the exception - literally):

> - 00010000000000000000000000000000 +
> - 00100000000000000000000000000000 =
> - 00110000000000000000000000000000 (same result as bitwise-or)

..**EXCEPT** if the masks you add have any set bits in common, such as adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to a bit-mask that already contains it- then we get pictures of crying kittens or some-such nonsense:

> - 00110000000000000000000000000000 +
> - 00100000000000000000000000000000 =
> - 01010000000000000000000000000000 /!\ Oops.
>
> Accidentally removed FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and accidentally added FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY; *two errors for the price of one keystroke!*

**Please, do the right thing(tm) and use '|' (not '+') for merging bit-masks.**

Here's a simple Java example of [bitwise-or](http://snipt.org/vgxg5) and the pitfalls of using addition on them.

Just found an excellent explanation of [bit-masks](http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2011/05/31/Using-e2809core2809d-to-combine-A-and-B-Explaining-that-bitmask-thing.aspx), too.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the [Android developer's website](http://developer.android.com) is actually pretty good for the "learning how to program via Android" crowd.

I would start by either taking a look at the example projects bundled with the sdk, or would work my way through the tutorials online, starting here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Personally, I learn best by taking some existing project and starting to make small tweaks to learn how stuff works.

I would guess that the "flag" that you want to set is actually on an Activity, but working through the tutorial/sample code will help you learn that terminology as well.

Hope that helps you get started, good luck!

Comment: I would say that I already apply everything you have said, but when I encounter such a trivial problem (like not knowing how to set a flag) it becomes aggravating to have to have to create a new question on SO. So, is there any experienced developer that can tell me step by step on how to figure out how to set a flag?

Comment: Why do you want to set that flag? The documentation shows it being set on a class that extends ScrollView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int)

Comment: Reading the documentation, I feel like my code should work. But doesn't. Code updated in my question. Also, I had the wrong flag posted as well. I am making a game and need the buttons to be dimmed. Hence `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE`.

Comment: "setSystemUiVisibility" is a method on View, but you're trying to call if from within a class that extends Activity... check out this question for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660638/possible-to-make-setsystemuivisibility-affect-the-entire-system-rather-than-j

Comment: Perfect, that example works, but how the hell am I supposed to know this? `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);`